# Showing a function is a function of only a variable $\eta(x,t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation, dimensional-analysis

Suppose I have a differential equation $$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}$$ satisfied by $\theta(x,t)$ and I then had that $\theta(x,t)=k F(x,t)$, and I know $F(x,t)$ is dimensionless. What is a general method in this situation to answer the question "Show  $F$ is a function of only the similarity variable $\eta=\eta(x,t)$"?

I am not really sure how to approach this as I don't recall ever encountering a problem like this. Any help apprecieted.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M546/SimSol1.pdf) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mattos I have seen a few documents like this, but they all seem to say "suggest a solution of the form $F(\xi)$ rather than proving that the solution must be of this form. Is there any way to prove that?

Comment: The solution to the heat equation can take many different forms, depending on boundary conditions, initial conditions and domain type. The solution you are asking for is just _one_ particular type of solution, named a similarity solution, which is a solution which is invariant under a stretching transformation. By taking *particular* products between the variables themselves and also with the original function, you can remove the scaling factor entirely which yields an invariant solution to the original PDE.

Comment: @Mattos Ah yes, I do understand that. So if I gave the exact BCs and ICs, then it would be possible to prove that $F(x,t)=F(\eta)$ only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take another example, the 1D wave equation: $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0.$$
Take $u(x,t) = U(x \pm ct)$, then $u$ satisfies the wave equation. Of course initial and boundary conditions also need to be taken into account, this will set $U$.

Can you work out an equivalent way for your (heat?) equation?

Comment: Yes, I am working with the heat equation. My question was about how to find the $\eta$ and show that the solution is a function of $\eta$ only. I can see that for the heat equation, the quantity equivalent to the $x+ct$ here is $x/\sqrt{t}$ but how can you justify/prove that $F$ is a function of this only?

Comment: In your example, also $U(x-ct)$ would work too, so it is possible that $u(x,t)$ is given by a combination of these, and so isn't exclusively a function of one of these - so how can you be sure? (Of course it is different for the heat equation).

Comment: If you exhibit a solution and can show uniciy, then you're done, aren't you?

Comment: Oh ok, yes you're right. So how can I show that $F(x,t)=F(\eta)$ is unique without determining $F$ explicitly?

Comment: I have determined that if $F(x,t)$ solves the wave equation, then so does $F(\lambda x, \lambda^2 t)$. So $F(\eta)$ would account for this scaling property, where $\eta(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$. But how can I then conclude that $F$ is a function of $\eta$ only?

Comment: What is the equation that $G(\eta)$ verifies, with $G(\eta(x,t))=F(x,t)$?

Comment: $F(x,t)+t \frac{∂F}{∂t}-αt \frac{∂^2 F}{∂x^2 }=0$

Comment: I had that $\theta$ solves the wave equation and was of the form $\theta=a+btF(x,t)$, so I substituted this into the wave equation to obtain the equation in the above comment.